# Export HTML with SVG chart to PDF

Tags: .net, svg

Is there any library that supports exporting html and SVG to PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [EVOPDF](http://www.evopdf.com/), it's been working great so far with SVG's and complex HTML.

Comment: I use EVOPDF. it won't render anything from D3.js

Answer (score 0):

I'd render the SVG separately from the HTML and include it as an image file from within the HTML code.

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is a free and open source html renderer, so maybe it'll work for you. Better yet, it might even render SVG by default.

Comment: I had posted an answer (now deleted) that suggested wkhtmltopdf, but when I tried it, it didn't work with SVGs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I guess you'll have to render them...

Answer (score 0):

Tried [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem and came across [EOpdf](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx)!. I tried the demo and it seems to work well, although it appears to rasterize SVG and canvas graphics?

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) Can generate PDFs from HTML with SVG images. However there are some requirements to the way SVG should be formatted and embedded in HTML. Please see my response to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395541/wkhtmltopdf-failure-when-embed-an-svg/12981972#12981972) to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf works with SVG as well and works perfect, but you might have to run it as different process as it is a command line tool.